# Structuring Data in Firestore in belongs-to and has-many relationship

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Coming from a SQL/Rails background I have a project I want to use Firebase/Firestore (with React) for and asking for help in setting up the data and collection structure.

"Models":

- Users
- Items
- Categories
- Locations

A user can have many items and an item belongs to a user.
A category can have many items and an item belongs to a category.

I need to be able to show all Categories, Locations and Items on the home page.
First I need to list all Items, and they're filterable by either Category and/or Location.

How do I best set that data up in Firestore?

*Sorry for the rails styled explanation, but SQL is all around my head.*

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: I‘d have an Index Component to query all Items as well as a Filter Component into which I‘d pass Categories and Locations. Clicking on an Item opens a new page in which I list more detailed information (title, description, ... and locations, categories).

Comment: Whats being asked is still unclear. A query is a filter so the comment is a bit confusing as well. Why don't you just have 4 collections. The items collection, for example, contains item documents which each have a *belongs_to_user* field and a users uid as a value? Same thing with items. Have an items collection where each item document has a field *belongs_to_category* field and a value of the category documentID? How does Locations tie in? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: I assume Item is somehow related with Location or User ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *suppose* you are thinking in terms of foreign keys as in a sql DB. What usually happens in a nosql scenario is that you should avoid relations and -instead- flatten the relations into a "big" document (document=json object in nosql).

There is no specific recipie for this.

What Alex was trying to explaying is that you should consider which is the central element in your design. It seems this is the 'item' element.

A possible design could be:

- Store the category and location in plain into the json object representing your item.
- Then use an array to list the items in the front end
- Finally use the JS array.filter() function on the frontend to filter what is shown in response to user action.

If you need to show only the items belonging to a user, add a 'user' field into the 'item' document and ask firestore to return only those documents whose 'user' field matches your logged user.

This is a bit outdated but should help you understand data denormalization in nosql:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html?m=1

#### Edit

In reference to Jay answer and to the MongoDB article pointed in the comments, I've always struggled to keep a decision: if embed a datum or reference it, but I've always ended up embedding small docs.

Can you Jay share your experience?

I've always found quite boring to create additional queries on front-end to rejoin the required info (a-la sql), while seldomly I've got advantages in pointing other *small* docs. I suppose it mostly depends on the app design.

**In short**

I prefer something like

```js
users_collection > user_uuid_0
{
    "name": "John"
    "items": [
        {/*...plain item1 object here...*/},
        {/*...plain item2 object here...*/},
        /*...*/
    ]
}
```

Rather than:

```js
users_collection > user_uuid_0
{
    "name": "John"
    "items_ids":[
      "item_uuid_0",
      "item_uuid_1",
      /*...*/
    ]
}

---

items_collection > item_1
{
   /*all item fields*/
   "belong_to": "user_uuid_0"
}

items_collection > item_2
{
   /*all item fields*/
   "belong_to": "user_uuid_0"
}
```

The benefits of the latter solution are more flexibility and decoupling: you can change the user details without any impact on items and your payloads are smaller (if trafic size matter most than number of ops in your service).

the cons are: requires 2 queries to the DB (1 to grab the user doc and one to grab the items filtered by id) vs. just 1; it requires a number of operations on front-end to recollect everything vs. no added operation, as the former layout of the doc already embeds everything.

The former works well if:

- you have one-to-few relations (one to many tends towards uuid refs like suggested by Jay)
- your documents are small (otherwise Jay's solution is better again)
- if you are billed by the operation rather than the trafic size

When we think about a managed nosql database like firestore, where, usually, your 
CRUD API is basically a REST api or something quite close to it (no JPA, DTO projections or the so...) the first layout, in my experience, is a better fit.

But, again, this is mostly related to the app design and services costs.

Comment: This answer excels for it's design simplicity. I would like to mention this [article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) 
 series about modeling 1-to-many and many-to-one relationships in NoSQL. Although  article was made for MongoDB I still find the concepts explained therein useful.

Comment: @Happy-Monad, I was thinking about that article too.

Comment: @ChristophBerger This is a pretty solid answer and +1 for the Denormalizing is Normal article - I use that a lot when talking about structures. A few thoughts. I believe the suggestion here is to keep items in an array. While Firestore supports arrays, they are just not a great fit with NoSQL. There's a long list of reasons not to use them but for me, probably 90% of the time  I can craft a better way to structure and store data. Second thing is keeping data shallow - that's a winner for NoSQL every time.

Comment: Last thing is data duplication; while it's common practice and prevalent in the RTDB for querying etc, Firestore has capabilities that alleviate much of the need for duplicate data. Array-contains and compound queries are very helpful and the big one is [Collection Group Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). That's a game changer and addresses many cases where previously denormalized data would have been required. So. Don't over-denormalize! Keep your structures flat and feel free to use references documents instead of duplicate data.

Comment: This whole discussion is extremely valuable  and much appreciated . Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplistic approach but it does address the requirements outlined in the question.

You will need four collections, one for each of the categories mention in the question, and then the documenents within each will contain information about that item plus a reference to who 'owns' that document

```
Users
   uid_0
      name: "Kirk"
   uid_1
      name: "McCoy"
   uid_2
      name: "Spock"

Items
   item_0
      name: "Communicator"
      belongs_to_user: uid_0
      category: "cat_0"
      location: "location_3"
   item_1
      name: "Tricorder"
      belongs_to_user: "uid_1"
      category: "cat_0"
      location: "location_2"
   item_2
      name: "Captains Chair"
      belongs_to_user: "uid_0"
      category: "cat_2"
      location: "location_0"
   item_3
      name: "Science station"
      belongs_to_user: "uid_2"
      category: "cat_1"
      location: "location_0"

Categories
   cat_0
      name: "Hand held devices"
   cat_1
      name: "Stations"
   cat_2
      name: "Furniture"

Locations
   location_0
      name: "Bridge"
   location_1
      name: "Engine Room"
   location_2
      name: "Sick Bay"
   location_3
      name: "Shore leave"
```

> A user can have many items and an item belongs to a user.

The users data is stored within the users collection, with the documentId being the users ID. In the above example, the user Kirk (uid_0) has two items, item_0 (a communicator) and item_2 (a captains chair). Likewise user McCoy has a tricorder and Spock as a Science Station.

> A category can have many items and an item belongs to a category.

In the example, we have three categories and both the Communicator and Tricorder belong to cat_0, Hand held devices.

> First I need to list all Items, and they're filterable by
>   either Category and/or Location.

The above structure will enable you get a a list of all items. Then they can be filtered by users, by which category they belong to and by location.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed i sight, I will try both appriaches!

Comment: But what content type would you choose for the references?

Comment: @ChristophBerger Strings! DocumentId's can only be strings so that's the only option.

Comment: Thank you @Jay! Much appreciated, I'll give it a try, your solution looks really clean and SQL-alike.

Comment: @ChristophBerger If it ends up being the solution, please accept it so it can help others.